# Onclick JavaScript Error - Expected ' ) '

Tags: javascript, error, button

On the case object, I get the following error (pic below) whenever I click **Troubleshoot**, **Problem**, or **Solution** button. I can fix the code, but I can't find where it's located. Can someone suggest where this code is located?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are most likely custom buttons, found in **Setup** > **Customize** > **Cases** > **Buttons, Links, and Actions**

In there you'll find OnClick Javascript buttons named Troubleshoot, Problem, and Solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look and report back shortly.

Comment: @IsBoyd I made a mistake and accidentally said Customize > Accounts. I changed my answer to Customize > Cases as this was your use case

Comment: I don't see them listed there.

Comment: @IsBoyd are these buttons located on the case page layout, next to the standard Edit/Delete/Clone buttons? If so, they must be custom buttons found in `Setup > Customize > Cases > Buttons, Links, and Actions` - if you are not referring to page detail buttons then please provide more information/screenshots of where your button is located on the page. Is the button part of a managed package?

Comment: Ok, just looked at the record with the issue. The buttons are on ActivityHistory object.

Comment: Ok, I found them. Activities > Task Buttons, Links, and Actions

Comment: Problem all solved. The original code writer used single quote instead of double quotes in the JavaScript code. @Morgan Marchese, thanks for helping me steer to where the buttons were located. I had a brain fart.